# Creating a subscribe feature (linking multiple tables?)?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I currently have 3 sql tables "news" "content" and "users". 
What I'm trying to achieve here is a subscribe/follow feature that allows users to follow anything listed inside the "content" table and then receive notifications whenever news is added regarding that content to the "news table". Will I need to link the 2 tables "content" and "news"in some way?. Other than I don't have any ideas at the moment. Any help will be really appreciated!

Comment: You're looking for InnoDB tables, indexing reference columns and creating foreign key constraints for those.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `TRIGGER` on the `news` table. The trigger action will perform a `JOIN` to find the users who are following the related content.